# PHP - Determine if the date is in the future using DateTime Object

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to determine whether a date is in the future or not, using `DateTime` objects but it always comes back positive:

```
$opening_date = new DateTime($current_store['openingdate']);
$current_date = new DateTime();
$diff = $opening_date->diff($current_date);
echo $diff->format('%R'); // +

if($diff->format('%R') == '+' && $current_store['openingdate'] != '0000-00-00' && $current_store['openingdate'] !== NULL) {
    echo '<img id="openingsoon" src="/img/misc/openingsoon.jpg" alt="OPENING SOON" />';
}
```

The problem is it's always positive so the image shows when it shouldn't be.

I must be doing something stupid, but what is it, it's driving me insane!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It's easier than you think. You can do comparisons with [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) objects:

```
$opening_date = new DateTime($current_store['openingdate']);
$current_date = new DateTime();

if ($opening_date > $current_date)
{
  // not open yet!
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You don't need a `DateTime` object for this. Try this:

```
$now = time();
if(strtotime($current_store['openingdate']) > $now) {
     // then it is in the future
}
```

Comment: You use DateTime objects because it's *better*, not because of any other reasons. `strtotime()`'s range is somewhat limited, but DateTime can work with a much wider range.

Answer (score 6):

You can compare DateTime objects with the usual comparison operators:

```
  $date1 = new DateTime("");                                                   
  $date2 = new DateTime("tomorrow");

  if ($date2 > $date1) {
      echo '$date2 is in the future!';
  }
```

For your current code, try this:

```
$opening_date = new DateTime($current_store['openingdate']);
$current_date = new DateTime();

if ($opening_date > $current_date) {
    echo '<img id="openingsoon" src="/img/misc/openingsoon.jpg" alt="OPENING SOON" />';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$opening_date = new DateTime('2018-07-04');
$current_date = new DateTime();

   if ($opening_date > $current_date) {
      echo "future date";
   }
```